# Pandas: Need to reconcile 3 data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I've been banging my head against this. Here's a sample of data frames I have:

df_users:

```
Email                        Roles
johndoe0@example.com
johndoe1@example.com
johndoe2@example.com
johndoe3@example.com
johndoe4@example.com
```

df_groups:

```
Group1                  Group2                  Group3
johndoe0@example.com    johndoe4@example.com    johndoe0@example.com
johndoe1@example.com                            johndoe1@example.com
johndoe4@example.com                            johndoe2@example.com
                                                johndoe3@example.com
```

df_roles:

```
          Group1    Group2    Group3
Role 1    True      False     False
Role 2    False     True      True
Role 3    False     False     True
```

Here's what I need the output to be:

```
Email                   Roles
johndoe0@example.com    Role 1
johndoe0@example.com    Role 2
johndoe0@example.com    Role 3
johndoe1@example.com    Role 1
johndoe2@example.com    Role 2
johndoe3@example.com    Role 3
johndoe2@example.com    Role 2
johndoe2@example.com    Role 3
johndoe3@example.com    Role 2
johndoe3@example.com    Role 3
johndoe4@example.com    Role 1
```

I tried doing this in Excel. One of the challenges it that in the actual data, there are hundreds of emails, >100 roles, and dozens of groups.

What I'm thinking of is something like:

```
# Prepare yourself for bad pseudo-code

for each user in df_users
    for each group in in df_groups
        if the user is in the group:
           if the row value is 'True' in df_roles:
               add the value of the first column in df_roles to the 'Roles' column in df_users...
           if a role already exists, append it with a ',' delimiter
```

Hopefully that shows what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
# data structure that will hold tuple of user and role
users_roles = []


# function that creates sets in order to optimize the search
def create_sets(users_groups):
    list_sets = []
    for col in list(users_groups.columns):
        s = set(list(users_groups[col]))
        if '' in s:
            s.remove('')
        list_sets.append(s)
    return list_sets


all_groups_sets = create_sets(df_groups)

for user in list(df_users['Email']):
    for idx, group_set in enumerate(all_groups_sets):
        if user in group_set:
            for i in range(len(df_roles)):
                if df_roles.iloc[i][idx]:
                    users_roles.append((user, 'Role' + ' ' + str(i+1)))

final = pd.DataFrame(users_roles, columns=['Email', 'Role'])
```

Comment: if the answer helped you please approve it as the solution